# Align the text in datagrid view in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

In c# winforms I need to paint text in DataGridView column header,I have a trouble to align the text to center because of the sorting glyph, how can I paint the text to align center according to the cell width.I dont want to remove the sorting functionality,but i need to remove the space for sorting glyph

Comment: put your related code here

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
this.dgData.Columns["Name"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = 
DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

Comment: This has a problem the space in left side will be larger

Comment: Updated with "MiddleCenter". Try now

Comment: the problem with this is because of the space reserved for sort glyph the space on right side will be larger

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in dgvBreakDowns.Columns)
{
col.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;   
}
```